# hibernate5 + spring boot connect multiple databases

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I want to use hibernate to connect two different databases and use different sessionfactory to operate the data

In the example below , Another datasource and LocalSessionFactoryBean will be added in the @Configuration class , but how do I give these two sessionFactory specific names?

### Reference:

https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-spring

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConf {

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
          {"com.baeldung.hibernate.bootstrap.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("sa");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
          = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
          "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
          "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

#### Want to reach the effect:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TestRepositoryImpl implements TestRepository{

    @Qualifier("connectionA")
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Qualifier("connectionB")
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
...
...
}
```

#### Another project example:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "test1DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.test1")
    public DataSource test1DataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "test2DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.test2")
    public DataSource test2DataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "test1Connection")
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate test1JdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("test1DataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name ="test2Connection")
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate test2JdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("test2DataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve hibernate with two Database: use session factory like below.

But i recommend use Spring Data JPA it will give more specification and easier to understand.

```
 public class Transfer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // get the SessionFacotry
        SessionFactory connectionAFactory = HibernateConf.getSessionFactory();
        SessionFactory connectionBFactory= DataSourceConfig.getSessionFactory();
        // get The Session
        Session connectionASes = HibernateConf.getSession();
        Session connectionBSes = DataSourceConfig.getSession();
```

Comment: if you dont understand i recommend to watch a video from below link:
https://youtu.be/Oo11SRzgXU4

Answer (score 0):

For this you can configure your data connection beans like this:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "test1DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.test1")
    public DataSource test1DataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "test2DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.test2")
    public DataSource test2DataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "test1Connection")
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate test1JdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("test1DataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name ="test2Connection")
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate test2JdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("test2DataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

After that you can autowire them separately by using @Qualifier in following way in your service class:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TestRepositoryImpl implements TestRepository{

    @Qualifier("test1Connection")
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory1;

    @Qualifier("test2Connection")
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory2;
...
...
}
```